# image in sd card not getting deleted in lollipop by calling getcontentResolver.delete()

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard

I am using this method `getcontentResolver.delete(MediaStore.images.media.external_content_uri,MediaStore.images.Media.data+"='"+imagepath,null)` to delete image file.it is working in kitkat and below versions but cant seems to find why it is not working in lollipop. please point me in the right direction.

Comment: maybe You have to update the MediaStore with something like this:  sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(YourImageFile)));

Comment: I already sent broadcast to update the mediastore and checked by restarting device but the image was still there.